# Complex Integral of $(\exp(z)-\exp(-z))/z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

How should I evaluate the following integral: $$\int_\gamma \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{z^n}dz,$$where $\gamma$ is the unit circle and $n\in\Bbb N$.

My work on the integral has been to parametrize the unit circle, so I get the integral to $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{e^{i\theta}}-e^{-e^{i\theta}}}{e^{in\theta}}ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta=i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{e^{i\theta}}-e^{-e^{i\theta}}}{e^{i(n-1)\theta}}\,d\theta.$$I got to this point, and I wasn't sure how to finish evaluating the integral.

Will someone provide only a *hint*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the integrand has a pole at $z=0$.  What is the Laurent series?

Comment: Laurent series have not been introduced in the course. Officially, we're about two chapters into Stein and Shakarchi's book, but this is not an exercise from the book, just from the professor.

Comment: @Clayton, if you are two chapters into that book, you probably know Cauchy's theorem already. Now write $e^z = 1 + z + \cdots + z^n/n! + g(z)$, where $g(z)$ is the tail. (Note that $g(z)/z^n$ is holomorphic). Do the same thing for $e^{-z}$, what can you conclude?

Comment: @Sanchez: Ah, now that makes sense! Let me work on it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use Cauchy's integral formula.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the residue theorem yet? The expression inside your integral is equivalent to $2i \frac{\sin{z}}{z^{n}}$ which has a pole order $n$ at $z=0$. If $n>1$ we do the following to find the residue 
$$ \text{res}(f,0)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim\limits_{z \to 0}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial z^{n-1}}z^{n}\frac{2i \sin{z}}{z^{n}}= \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim\limits_{z \to 0}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial z^{n-1}}2i \sin{z}$$
Note that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial z^{n-1}}\sin{z}=\sin{\left(z+(n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$. This implies that
$$ \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim\limits_{z \to 0}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial z^{n-1}}2i \sin{z}=\frac{2i}{(n-1)!}\lim\limits_{z \to 0}\sin{\left(z+(n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=\frac{2i\sin{\left((n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}}{(n-1)!}$$
Which by trig identities gives us 
$$ \frac{-2i\cos{n}}{(n-1)!} $$
Since this is a pole order $n$ it is counted $n$ times which means that 
$$ \int 2i \frac{\sin{z}}{z^{n}} dz=2 \pi i n \frac{-2i\cos{n}}{(n-1)!}=\frac{4 \pi \cos{n}}{(n-1)!}$$. 
If $n=1$ we take 
$$ \text{res}(f,0)=\lim\limits_{z \to 0}2i \sin{z}=0$$
Which means our integral is 
$$ \int 2i \frac{\sin{z}}{z} dz=2 \pi i 0=0$$

Comment: I’m so far past the residue theorem at this point haha thanks, though, for making an attempt. For such an old question, instead of leaving out any details, you should include a full solution (or near-full solution) as an aid to any future readers. Also, I think the residue theorem is precisely what user Robert Israel was hinting at regarding the Laurent series.

Comment: I did answer before looking at the time it was posted lol. I'll edit in more stuff